# How to make ASP.NET/React app serve SPA from subpath?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core

I have a stock `aspnetcore` and `reactjs` app, generated from the starter template (`dotnet new react`).  I would like the SPA app to be served from a subpath off the root url; e.g. instead of the sample app being `https://localhost:5001/counter` I'm looking for it to instead be served from `https://localhost:5001/myapp/counter`.

I changed the `Startup.cs` from:

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

to this:

```
app.Map(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/myapp"), appMember =>
            {
                appMember.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                    if (env.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                    }
                });
            });
```

This sort of works.  If I browse to `https://localhost:5001/myapp/` it appears to load the index.html, but the static files are attempting to load from the root path and not the subpath.

What needs to be changed so that the react app uses the subpath as the root? I'd like this to work both in the interactive VS dev environment and when deployed, likely on IIS.  It seems like it's close but I'm missing something.

Sample demo of the solution is available here: https://github.com/petertirrell/mvc-spa-demo/tree/master/mvc-spa-demo

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this by any chance?

Comment: I just finished testing this on Azure now. Please see my answer below, BR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with moving app to sub-path by adding this to top of package.json:

```
"homepage": "/myapp/",
```

When running `npm start` inside ClientApp folder, app is now serving `http://localhost:3000/myapp`

Then change `Startup.cs` like this:

First remove

```
app.UseSpaStaticFiles()
```

then add

```
        const string spaPath = "/myapp";
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(spaPath)
                               || ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/sockjs-node"),
                client =>
            {
                client.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                });
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.Map(new PathString(spaPath), client =>
            {
                // `https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3147`
                client.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
                {
                    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                    {
                        if (ctx.Context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments($"{spaPath}/static"))
                        {
                            // Cache all static resources for 1 year (versioned file names)
                            var headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                            headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                            {
                                Public = true,
                                MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365)
                            };
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Do not cache explicit `/index.html` or any other files.  See also: `DefaultPageStaticFileOptions` below for implicit "/index.html"
                            var headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                            headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                            {
                                Public = true,
                                MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(0)
                            };
                        }
                    }
                });

                client.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                    spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions()
                    {
                        OnPrepareResponse = ctx => {
                            // Do not cache implicit `/index.html`.  See also: `UseSpaStaticFiles` above
                            var headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                            headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                            {
                                Public = true,
                                MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(0)
                            };
                        }
                    };
                });
            });
        }
```

Don't forget to clear browser history before testing changes for the first time on e.g. Azure.

Answer (score 4):

You can do so by having:

```cs
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
});
```

in your `ConfigureServices` and:

```cs
string spaPath = "/myapp";
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.MapWhen(y => y.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(spaPath), client =>
    {
        client.UseSpa(spa => 
        {
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        });
    });
}
else
{
    app.Map(new PathString(spaPath), client =>
    {
        client.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        client.UseSpa(spa => {});
    });
}
```

It should be noted that in development we use `.MapWhen` because `.Map` would cause your static files to be available at `/myapp/myapp/[file]` as opposed to `/myapp/[file]`.

Comment: How can the React dev server proxy be setup with .Net Framework 4.6? With .Net Core it's simple to use UseReactDevelopmentServer, but this isn't available in .Net Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I combined some of each answer to get it working.  You need to add the `"homepage": "/myapp"` to the `package.json` as well as the config changes to `Startup.cs`.  I used the simpler config provided in [Shoe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63656067/140263) without all the extra caching and sockets directives, as I don't need those.

Because my application also used [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/) for SPA routing under `/myapp` I also needed to add `basename` to the root `BrowserRouter`:

`<BrowserRouter basename="/myapp" >...</BrowserRouter>`