# React routing with MVC routing, what's happening here?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I am very new to react and trying to build an app with a react front end and MVC/web API backend. I am running into an issue.

All I've done is created a sample ASP.NET core web app with react, based on the included Visual Studio template. `dotnet new react`. I've made no other changes to this code.

This app is currently deployed to an Azure app service at: https://examplemvcreact.azurewebsites.net/

**Expected:** If I visit the url https://examplemvcreact.azurewebsites.net/weatherforecast, I would expect, the weatherforecast controller is called, and its data returned.

**Actual result:** I get what appears to be a blank index page, with the header rendered correctly.

**However, I also notice:** that if I do a full refresh, control+f5, on the url https://examplemvcreact.azurewebsites.net/weatherforecast , it **DOES** in fact hit the controller and give me the data.

Can anyone help me understand how this routing is working? Locally, I don't have this issue.

thank you!

Comment: You are most likely experiencing cache issues. Please see my post here to avoid it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64062989/14072498

Comment: @RoarS. the caching wasn't my issue per se, but you definitely lead me down the right road of finding the solution. It was the pesky service worker! I disabled that for now in my index.js, and I can now load the pages as expected, thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

It was the service worker. I removed the import and call in my index.js file, and my mvc calls are now going back to the server as expected.