# ASP.NET Core + React | Correct way to structure files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, file-structure

What is the correct way to structure files in real life application?

By default, if I'm correct, ASP.NET Core projects files should be structured as:

[Solution]

- [Project]

  - Dependencies
  - Properties
  - Controllers
  - Models
  - Repositories
  - wwwroot
  - Pages
  - Startup.cs
  - Program.cs
  - appsettings.json

For any static file it should be inside a wwwroot folder, right?

But then why creating a ASP.NET Core project with React + redux template makes a folder 'ClientApp' instead of 'wwwroot' and places all react code in there with folders 'src' 'public'?

I know that you can do that and then in startup.cs enable it with 'app.UseSpaStaticFiles();', But why? Is it just to make it simpler or does it have real life benefits? Should I structure my files same way too?

And if I suppose, or can, use with 'wwwroot', how should wwwroot folder look? I know that wwwroot folder suppose to contain all the static files such as css, images and js

wwwroot

- css
- js
- images

Since react is a js library/framework, should all code be inside js folder like this

wwwroot

- css
- js

  - src

    - actions
    - components
    - store
    - ...
- images

I been trying to find an answer but everywhere everyone has a different answer.

On a side note, also if using scss, or similar, should all the scss be inside css folder or should there be a scss folder inside wwwroot that on compile saves css code inside css folder?

Comment: It is a reason why React-app is kept separate in `ClientApp` folder. Maybe this will be more clear to you if you read up on `create-react-app`. There are already issues with React-app embedded inside asp.net Core projects, hence I wouldn't leave that path unless you have unlimited of time/patience :-) Merry X-mas

Comment: @RoarS. So what you saying is if I am not using a cra (create react app) but something else that does not have same issues, I should split up the code to `wwwroot`? If so, how do I handle all the components and actions in the folder? is it like how I presented `folders js -> src -> (actions, components so on)`? 
I am not planning to stay with cra on my asp.net core project. Just want to know how I should structure the files :) 
But thank you for the insight why by default its inside a `ClientApp`. 
Thank you and Merry xmas to you too :)

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that `React + redux template` is kind of a hack to make React working inside an asp.net Core-project. Is is very neat during devel with Hot Module Reload. I would never recommend to try to blend your React-app into your asp.net Core folder structure. In larger projects, APIs and front-end apps are kept separate.

Comment: I see. Thank you, this helped out a lot :)

Comment: Your quite welcome :-) If you decide to deploy such an app to e.g. Azure, please read my post on configuring caching for production: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64062989/14072498